# Google Map API V3 directionsService.route not work in mvc 4

Tags: jquery-ui, google-maps, asp.net-mvc-4, google-maps-api-3, dialog

In my dialog cannot  route map direction

```
<script>

var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService(); 


function calcRoute() {  
    var myLoc = MyLoc; // My location 
    var Dest = DesLoc; // Destination Location

    var request = {
        origin: myLoc,
        destination: Dest,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };   

    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {           
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);             
         }
    });
}

function initialize() {      
    myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    var mapOptions = {
        center: myLatLng,
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("maplarge_canvas"),
                    mapOptions);

    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        suppressMarkers: true
    });
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);       
}

function success(position) {
    document.getElementById("hidMyLoc").value = position.coords.latitude + ',' + position.coords.longitude;
} 

$(function () {
   // google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    initialize();
});
```

in function calcroute() can not run through. directionsService.route(request, function (response, status)

in my html

```
<input type="button" id="btn_submit" value="Get Direction" onclick="calcRoute();" />
<div id="maplarge_canvas" style="width: 850px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

When click button  to call  calRoute() function

this Function can not run  through directionService.route  and firebug can not see error in js

PS.  This Code run on Dialog Jquery UI

Answer (score 0):

I believe this comes very late but just by looking at it and for the future viewing

```
google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
```

should be

```
google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
```